# Is it possible to create a virtual drive and share via USB?

Tags: usb-drive

My question is kind of hard to follow, but I'm asking if it's possible to make a virtual flash drive and sync it to another device with a USB to USB cable?

To make things more clear, think of a typical flash drive. You connect it to a laptop and it shows up as a removable disk. Is it possible to make a computer a host of a "Virtual Drive" that would be connected to a USB cord on one end, and the other end connecting to another device such as a Xbox 360, or another computer.

Comment: For something like that, it might just be easier to setup an internet share with Samba or something. This would work if you are looking to access the data from both computers at the same time.